# Magento secure trading payment method need to hold a payment option

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment-gateway

In my magento store have many customers. I want to offer my old customer with this special option.

(i.e) **No need to pay at the end of the sale**. They can pay later with their outstanding invoices by online mode. Is there any possible to set this option with magento store.

I m using Secure trading payment gateway.

Thanks

Comment: Magento has it's own Stack Exchange place, try here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What a great question. 1+

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You could implement payment method for special customer group and this payment method Will only generate invoice for the sales order and set its status to Pending.

Then you will do another module that add tab to the customer account page ( for example Pending Invoices ), And this module generate payment form based on invoice/order data and when they pay it you mark the invoice as paid and captured.

#### Its straight forward concept if you know that Magento Invoices has Statuses ( Paid, Pending, Canceled ) And you can check the invoices from sales->invoice ( just like the orders !)